# applescript in filemaker pro stopped understanding the word "document"

Tags: filemaker

I have been using a native AppleScript in FileMaker pro which has been working until today.
I am trying to save a word document using a set variable, however, I am being told
"Expected end of the line, etc. but found class name."
the offending expression is 
"tell application "Microsoft Word"
    activate
    open thetemplate
save as active **document** file name docc" and the document is the offending word.
What is going on? why has this suddenly stopped working?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of the AppleScript question then FileMaker, next time try to add "AppleScript" tag

It looks like AppleScript syntax changed for MS Word at some point so

```
tell application "Microsoft Word" activate
```

does not work anymore. Try to change to this:

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    activate
end tell
```

Comment: I did this and it made no difference. Its now stopping at this: tell application "Microsoft Word"
 open thetemplate
 save as active document file name doccc
end tell

Comment: Are you using AppleScript as one line or you just did not format your code? Could you post how it is formatted in FileMaker exactly.